# Why is cronjob stoping the script execution after 60 seconds?

Tags: cron, npm

`0 8 * * * /usr/local/bin/npm --prefix /root/myscript run start > /root/logs`

I can see at the log file that this script STARTS execution at 8am.

Although, if the script does exceed more than 60 seconds running: it stops.

I know it has nothing to do with the script because it has proper error handling that would get outputted to logs: which is not the case.

The script simply stops at 8:01am.

It seems like crontab stops it, just like when we hit `CTRL+C`.

Comment: I'd check the system log or cron's journal (`journalctl`) for relevant messages. Does npm have a verbose option? If yes, use it.

Comment: Maybe it takes 1 minute to figure out there's nothing to be done.

Comment: It's usually a lack of environment variables… try `env -i /usr/local/bin/npm …` from the shell, that might help narrowing it down.

Comment: As @UlrichSchwarz says. In particular, cron does not work as a login would -- it does not read your .profiles.

Comment: it's not about environment variables. If the node script doesn't hang for more than 1 minute, then it executes till the end.

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz

Comment: "_I know it has nothing to do with the script because it has proper error handling that would get outputted to logs: which is not the case._". Not true - you're ignoring _stderr_ output completely. Add `2>&1` to the end of the command so that `/root/logs` captures error messages as well as normal _stdout_ output

Comment: @roaima I did so, but no error has been outputted to /root/logs.